# XSLT node not selectable due to an empty namespace declaration

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I am getting KML files which have an empty namespace declaration for the description tag. They are as follows:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Placemark>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>10.42195,46.9603,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
    <Name>Hallo world</Name>
    <description xmlns="">My description
    </description>          
</Placemark>
...
</Document>
</kml>
```

I wrote an XSLT transformation which is as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="kml:Placemark">
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates select="description" />
</xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:element name="payload">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The `description` node is not selected. It will be selected if I delete the (empty) namespace declaration. I have seen similar problems already reported at SO and I've tried the proposed solutions but unfortunately none of them work for my problem.

How I can select the `description` node which contains the empty namespace declaration `xmlns=""` ?

Thanks!

EDIT: I am including the complete stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" 
xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
extension-element-prefixes="str">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4" />

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:param name="myExpirationDate" />
<xsl:param name="myTime" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="drive_ahead_message">

        <xsl:element name="header">
            <xsl:element name="version">1.0</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="messages">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:kml/kml:Document/kml:Placemark" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="kml:Placemark">
    <xsl:element name="message">
        <xsl:element name="message_id">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::kml:Placemark) + 1" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="timestamp">
            <xsl:value-of select="$myTime" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="expiration_date">
            <xsl:value-of select="$myExpirationDate " />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Name" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Point" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:description" />

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="kml:description">
    <xsl:element name="payload">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="kml:Name">
    <xsl:element name="cause">
        <xsl:element name="lang">en</xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="causename">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="kml:Point">
    <xsl:variable name="coords">
        <xsl:value-of select="./kml:coordinates" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="longitude">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($coords,',')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="rest">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($coords,',')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="latitude">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($rest,',')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="height">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($rest,',')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="position">

        <xsl:element name="latitude">
            <xsl:value-of select="$latitude" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="longitude">
            <xsl:value-of select="$longitude" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="height">
            <xsl:value-of select="$height" />
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Assuming the `kml` prefix is bound to the right namespace in your XSLT (and, if you're using XSLT 2.0, you _don't_ have `xpath-default-namespace` anywhere) then that should work correctly.  Can you post the complete stylesheet?

Comment: Sure. Stylesheet added. Thanks!

Comment: That stylesheet uses `kml:description` so it expects the `description` element to be in the main KML namespace.  For `<description xmlns="">` you'd have to apply-templates to/match on just `description`.

Comment: Sorry. Could you clarify your suggestion, please?. I've tried using <xsl:apply-templates select="description" /> where the template definition is <xsl:template match="description"> but didn't work. What should be declaration and the call? Thanks!

Comment: Using `<xsl:apply-templates select="description" />` and `<xsl:template match="description">` is the correct approach, I just tested that version of the stylesheet you supplied against your sample XML and it worked correctly for me.  Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: It's a bit odd that you've declared Xalan and EXSLT-related namespaces at the top of your stylesheet when the stylesheet itself is version 2.0 - those things only make sense with 1.0.

Comment: True. This was a copy paste error. Anyway, descriptions are not matched. I am using XMLspy for testing and I am also trying this using Java. In both cases descriptions are not matched.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, removing Xalan and EXSLT-related namespaces the problem has been solved.

Comment: No, the redundant namespaces have nothing to do with the stated problem. All that 's required here is to remove the `kml:` prefix when addressing the `description` element, in the two places it's used.